# Would the phrase, "in Florida," be an introductory clause?

Tags: phrases

Would the phrase "*in Florida*" be an introductory phrase in the sentence,

> "*In Florida, I visited my cousin.*"

And if so, would a comma go after "*today*" if it were added before "*in florida*"?

> Today[,] in Florida, I visited my cousin.*"

Comment: How it sounds when read is a good guide as to whether one should include a comma. I'd certainly want the emphasis / gravitas the comma gives to the introductory _in Florida_ in your first example. // The second seems to need two sentences' worth of gravitas.

Comment: No, you need to add "while" to make it a verbless clause: "while in Florida, ..." which would then be a supplementary adjunct (your "introductory clause"). As it stands it's just an awful preposed element that should be "I visited my cousin in Florida". You can front the adjunct "today" (a comma would be optional) or place it at the end with no comma - it's a free choice.

Comment: How about "Today, while I was in Florida, I visited my cousin"? Would commas go before and after "while I was in Florida"?

Comment: Yes, commas would be okay.

Comment: Just so you know, "In Florida" sounds less awkward at the end of this sentence.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it would only be an introductory clause if it started the sentence, as "introductory" implies "before anything else".

So I would say that "In Florida" is an introductory clause in your first example, but not in your second example.